# jquery ajax call return error same service works on local and other server

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

I am getting an error from a service which works on local system and on other domains (uploaded separately on each domain.) It returns the error:

`"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"`

The same service with same methods works on other domains.

Is there any issue regarding folder rights? If yes, can anyone tell what to change?

It is not a cross-browser issue as it is uploaded on same server from where I am accessing.

If I call this service from code behind by addding web reference then it works fine.

```
function GetHints(keyword, domain_id) {
    var dataString = "{keyword: '" + keyword + "',domain_id: '" + domain_id + "'}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/test.asmx/GetKeywordSearch?" + (new Date()).getTime() + "",
            data: dataString,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                var str = msg.d;
                alert(str);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you just alert out msg does the JSON appear to be correct, or do you even get JSON repsonse?

Comment: no @Bearcat9425 it always return error. the page HTML in response even status is ok

Comment: Well HTML isn't going to be JSON formatted hence the Unexpected Characters,  is there anything in the HTML that hints at errors or anything like that?

Comment: In my idea there is no issue in this request it is something with server. But i am not getting point what type of settings issue with daomain or access rights

Comment: @Addy is your function goes at success part?? also check test.asmx this file have you added script tag?[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] also debug your test.asmx  file

Comment: @BhavinChauhan it always return error. [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] is there i have checked all these.

Comment: is this work in localhost?? also tell me is this 3.5 framework??

Comment: @BhavinChauhan yes it works in local host framework is 4.0

Comment: just try this var dataString = "{'keyword': '" + keyword + "','domain_id': '" + domain_id + "'}";

Comment: please post GetKeywordSearch code

Comment: @BhavinChauhan get keyword search just return a comma separated  string no issue in there as same method works fine if it is uploaded on any other domain and data string  updating return same error

Comment: contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8", try this

Comment: is it solved? or still face an issue?

Comment: @BhavinChauhan Still same issue

Comment: @Addy is there <httpHandlers> tag in webconfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason that service was not working is web.config. i Was missing web.config service settings. Handlers for service that are mostly added by Visual studio. But it missed that. After addition of handlers it works fine